# Encapsulation and generalization function def mult_tasks(str_numbers) in python

Tags: python, iteration, encapsulation, generalization

The Question:

Without altering mult_tasks, write a definition for mult_tasks_line so that the
doctests pass.
So:

`print mult_tasks("3469")`  will produce:

```
(3*3) (3*4) (3*6) (3*9)
(4*3) (4*4) (4*6) (4*9)
(6*3) (6*4) (6*6) (6*9)
(9*3) (9*4) (9*6) (9*8)
```

---

```
def mult_tasks_line(first_num, str_numbers):

    """
    >>> mult_tasks_line("4", "3469")
    '(4*3) (4*4) (4*6) (4*9) '
    """
    #Add your code here

def mult_tasks(str_numbers):

    """
    >>> mult_tasks("246")
    '(2*2) (2*4) (2*6) \\n(4*2) (4*4) (4*6) \\n(6*2) (6*4) (6*6) \\n'
    >>> mult_tasks("1234")
    '(1*1) (1*2) (1*3) (1*4) \\n(2*1) (2*2) (2*3) (2*4) \\n(3*1) (3*2) (3*3) (3*4) \\n(4*1) (4*2) (4*3) (4*4) \\n'
    """

    #Do not alter any code in this function
    result_tasks = ""
    for ch in str_numbers:
        result_tasks += mult_tasks_line(ch, str_numbers) + "\n"
    return result_tasks


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod(verbose = True)
```

I have already tried doing this:

```
def mult_tasks_line(first_num, str_numbers):
    digits=0
    for num in str_numbers:
        while digits<len(str_numbers):
            print "("+first_num+"*"+str_numbers[digits]+")",
            digits=digits+1

def mult_tasks(str_numbers):
    result_tasks = ""
    for ch in str_numbers:
        result_tasks += mult_tasks_line(ch, str_numbers),"\n"
    return result_tasks
```

This is what I tried, the first function works pretty close, but it does not have the single quote. when run 
mult_tasks_line("4", "3469”) 
it comes out `(4*3) (4*4) (4*6) (4*9)`.

But the second function seems totally wrong. 
this is the result for the second function :

`mult_tasks("246”)`

```
(2*2) (2*4) (2*6) 

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module> mult_tasks("246")
File "/Users/HuesFile/Downloads/Mastery Test/2.py", line 25, in mult_tasks
result_tasks += mult_tasks_line(ch, str_numbers),"\n" 
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'tuple' objects
```

Comment: def mult_tasks_line(first_num, str_numbers):
    digits=0
    for num in str_numbers:
        while digits<len(str_numbers):
            print "("+first_num+"*"+str_numbers[digits]+")",
            digits=digits+1

Comment: def mult_tasks(str_numbers):
    #Do not alter any code in this function
    result_tasks = ""
    for ch in str_numbers:
        result_tasks += mult_tasks_line(ch, str_numbers),"\n"
    return result_tasks

Comment: this is what i tried, the first function works pretty close but it does not have the single quote. when run >>> mult_tasks_line("4", "3469”) it comes out
(4*3) (4*4) (4*6) (4*9). but the second one seems totally wrong. this is the result for the second function :>>> mult_tasks("246")
(2*2) (2*4) (2*6)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    mult_tasks("246")
  File "/Users/HuesFile/Downloads/Mastery Test/2.py", line 25, in mult_tasks
    result_tasks += mult_tasks_line(ch, str_numbers),"\n"
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'tuple' objects

Comment: Add these lines to your question.

Comment: Thx for suggetion, ive added them to question

Comment: add some code style, correct minor spelling error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously `mult_tasks` contains an incorrect line

```
result_tasks += mult_tasks_line(ch, str_numbers),"\n"
```

`result_tasks` is a string and here it is concatenated with a tuple (They are constructed by commas with or without parentheses) `mult_tasks_line(ch, str_numbers), "\n"` which leads to exception.

You need to modify this line to

```
result_tasks += mult_tasks_line(ch, str_numbers) + "\n"
```

Another problem in your code, is that `mult_tasks_line` doesn't return value, but simply prints it. You want to do something like this

```
def mult_tasks_line(first_num, str_numbers):
    result = []
    for ch in str_numbers:
        result.append('({}*{})'.format(first_num, ch))
    return ' '.join(result)
```

Comment: Thx Alik, your codes seems perfect and it is really helpful for my understanding. can you tell me more about the string.append() and ‘’.join() function, because i think i still haven’t learn these stuff at moment.

Comment: @user3521788  [`append`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) and [`join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) are desribed in docs. You can google a lot of examples (see [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_join.htm) or [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_append.htm)).

Comment: it’s amazing!  i really appreciate your help. Thx Alik

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, you want to print the matrix of ordered tuples from a string of number-characters,
while the seperator

```
def mult_tasks_line(first_num, str_numbers):
    return ''.join(
        ['({n1}*{n2}) '.format(n1 = first_num, n2 = n2 ) for n2 in str_numbers])

def mult_tasks(str_numbers):
    result_tasks = ""
    for ch in str_numbers: 
        result_tasks += mult_tasks_line(ch, str_numbers) + "\n" 
    return result_tasks
```

Then

```
print mult_tasks("3469")
```

gives

```
(3*3) (3*4) (3*6) (3*9) 
(4*3) (4*4) (4*6) (4*9) 
(6*3) (6*4) (6*6) (6*9) 
(9*3) (9*4) (9*6) (9*9)
```

as desired. The result scales, in the sense that it works for an arbitrary string.

Do you wish the multiplications to be computed?

Comment: print mult_tasks("3469")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    print mult_tasks("3469")
  File "/Users/HuesFile/Downloads/Mastery Test/2.py", line 8, in mult_tasks
    result_tasks += mult_tasks_line(ch, str_numbers) + "\n"
  File "/Users/HuesFile/Downloads/Mastery Test/2.py", line 2, in mult_tasks_line
    return string.join(['({n1}*{n2}) '.format(n1 = first_num, n2 = n2 ) for n2 in str_numbers ], sep = '')
NameError: global name 'string' is not defined

Comment: thx dude for your kind help, I tried your code but get the result showing as above. the question does not require compute the multiplication, but i think if it works out will be more helpful for me to understand what happens.

Comment: did you try `import string`;  I edited the code above